# Using GROUP_CONCAT column alias in CASE statement with LIKE

Tags: mysql, view, case, group-concat

The idea here is that the GROUP_CONCAT compiles a list of option codes out of the stock table joined to the option_stock and options tables, grouped by the stock id. 
An example row is this:

```
Name                Options             Transmission
'Holden Commodore' '111, 145, 166, 188' 'Auto'
```

This view works as it is, but I can't help but feel there's a more elegant solution?

```
CREATE VIEW stock_view AS
    (select s.description AS Name,
    group_concat(o.option_code order by o.option_code ASC separator ', ') 
    AS Options, 
    (case
        WHEN group_concat(o.option_code) LIKE '%111%' then 'Auto'
        WHEN group_concat(o.option_code) LIKE '%112%' then 'Manual'
        else 'Other'
    end) as Transmission
    from stock s
    join option_stock ost ON s.id = ost.stock_id
    join options o ON o.id = ost.option_id
    group by s.id)
```

I'm trying to avoid using this ugly looking GROUP_CONCAT inside CASE predicament, but I get an error saying the field `Options` does not exist if I use it inside the case statement like this:

```
WHEN `Options` LIKE '%111%' then 'Auto'
```

I know why the error is thrown - it's because you can't use the alias of another column in this manner. But is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

These bits do not seem reliable enough to me:

```
WHEN group_concat(o.option_code) LIKE '%111%' ...
WHEN group_concat(o.option_code) LIKE '%112%' ...
```

`LIKE '%111%'` will match e.g. `'111222, 145, 166, 188'` just as well as `'111, 145, 166, 188'`. Unless, of course, there are only 3-character codes and you aren't expecting that to change soon.

Still, I would probably use a different technique anyway, most likely a conditional COUNT or SUM. For instance:

```
(CASE
    WHEN SUM(o.option_code = '111') > 0 THEN 'Auto'
    WHEN SUM(o.option_code = '112') > 0 THEN 'Manual'
    ELSE 'Other'
END) AS Transmission
```

Note also that in your particular case the following, although rather specific, solution should work as well:

```
IFNULL(
    MIN(CASE o.option_code WHEN '111' THEN 'Auto' WHEN '112' THEN 'Manual' END),
   'Other'
) AS Transmission
```

I.e. if `'111'` or, for some reason, both `'111'` and `'112'` are found among the codes in the same group of rows, the `MIN()` will return `'Auto'`, if `'112'` bot not `'111'`, it will evaluate to `'Manual'`. Otherwise it will be NULL, in which case the `IFNULL()` function will evaluate to `'Other'`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test without the actual tables (can't actually execute the statement) but what about something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW stock_view AS
(SELECT
    gc.Name,
    gc.Options,
    (case
        WHEN gc.Options LIKE '%111%' then 'Auto'
        WHEN gc.Options LIKE '%112%' then 'Manual'
        else 'Other'
    end) as Transmission
FROM
    (select 
        s.description AS Name,
        group_concat(o.option_code order by o.option_code ASC separator ', ') AS Options
    from 
        stock s
        join option_stock ost ON s.id = ost.stock_id
        join options o ON o.id = ost.option_id
    group by 
        s.id) gc);
```

Comment: Will this work? I didn't think a SELECT could go inside a FROM in a view?

I used your answer as inspiration though, I created a second view


select s.id, group_concat(o.option_code order by o.option_code ASC separator ', ') as Options 
from `stock` `s`
join `option_stock` `ost` ON `s`.`id` = `ost`.`stock_id`
join `options` `o` ON `o`.`id` = `ost`.`option_id`
group by s.id


and added it to the join in my stock_view


so I can just use


when option_view.options LIKE '%111' THEN 'Auto'

sorry about formatting I don't know how to add new lines

Comment: You are right about the subquery in the FROM - sorry about that, has been a while.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate join to determine the transmission type:

```
CREATE VIEW stock_view AS
select
    s.description AS Name,
    group_concat(o.option_code order by o.option_code separator ', ') AS Options,
    if(t.option_code = '111', 'Auto', 'Manual') as Transmission
from stock s
join option_stock ost ON s.id = ost.stock_id
join options o ON o.id = ost.option_id
left join options t on t.id = ost.option_id 
     and option_code in ('111', '112')
group by s.id
```

Only one row will join from the transmission join (a car can't be both auto and manual) and this approach avoids all those sub queries.

Making the join a *left* join means that a missing transmission option will show as a manual. You can tune that by adding a test for null to have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two separate **VIEWS** because **MySQL** doesn't support sub-query in **VIEW**.

Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW stock_view AS
  SELECT s.description AS sname, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(o.option_code ORDER BY o.option_code SEPARATOR ', ')  AS soptions 
  FROM stock s
  INNER JOIN option_stock ost ON s.id = ost.stock_id
  INNER JOIN OPTIONS o ON o.id = ost.option_id
  GROUP BY s.id;

CREATE VIEW stock_view1 AS 
  SELECT sname, soptions, 
         (CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET('111', soptions) THEN 'Auto'
               WHEN FIND_IN_SET('112', soptions) THEN 'Manual'
               ELSE 'Other'
         END) AS Transmission
  FROM stock_view;
```